# Activation code is not displaying in url after click on the link

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

I am sending a link using email to create password but while sending link in an email i have attach my Activation Code also to display with link but it is not displaying when i click on link though in debugging i'm getting the link with Activation Code. Below is my code to add link in Body section

```
body+=@"<br /><a href='http://localhost:49234/Index.aspx?ActivationCode='"+objUserDetailsBE.ActivationCode+"'>Create a login to account</a>";
```

I am getting only till `http://localhost:49234/Index.aspx?ActivationCode=` in browser after click on the link Please let me know where i am doing wrong.
Adding code as per in comments:

```
string emailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text;
string subject = "Login Credentials For Nth Star";
string body = string.Format("Hello,");                        
body+=@"<br /><a href='http://localhost:49234/Index.aspx?ActivationCode='"+objUserDetailsBE.ActivationCode+"'>Create a login to account</a>";
Email.SendMail(objemail, emailAddress, subject, body, "");
```

and below is my 'SendMail' method

```
public static bool SendMail(EmailConfigurationBE objEmailConfig, string toEmailAddresses, string subject, string body, string mailAttachments)
    {
        char[] splitter = { ';' };
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(objEmailConfig.Email);
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mailMessage.Body = body;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        string[] multi = toEmailAddresses.Split(';');
        string[] multipath = mailAttachments.Split(';');
        foreach (string MultiemailId in multi)
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(MultiemailId));
        }
        if (mailMessage.To.Count > 0)
        {
            //Adding Multiple Attachments
            if (mailAttachments != "")
            {
                foreach (string Multipath1 in multipath)
                {
                    Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(Multipath1);
                    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
                }

            }
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            try
            {
                smtpClient.Host = objEmailConfig.SMTPServer;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = EnableSsl;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = objEmailConfig.Email;
                NetworkCred.Password =objEmailConfig.Password;
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtpClient.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtpClient.Port =Convert.ToInt32(objEmailConfig.PortNumber);
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {

                mailMessage = null;
                smtpClient = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a bigger chunk of code? It is not clear at all where you are generating this, and how are you using this "body" variable afterwards

Comment: @Andrei now check and let me know if anything more is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simple quoting problem. Look

`<a href='http://localhost:49234/Index.aspx?ActivationCode='"+objUserDetailsBE.ActivationCode+"'`

In here you have a single quote before `http`, another one after `ActivationCode=` and third one at the end. Looks like one is redundant, and that breaks your markup.

Correct version:

```
body+=@"<br /><a href='http://localhost:49234/Index.aspx?ActivationCode="+objUserDetailsBE.ActivationCode+"'>Create a login to account</a>";
```

The only change I did was to remove the single quote after `ActivationCode=`.

Also make sure the active code does not contain symbols like quotes or `<>`, that can also break the markup.